# CakePHP rewrite Strings

Tags: string, cakephp, url-rewriting, formhelper

I'd like to know if it's possible to use CakePHP's function to rewrite strings.

For example, the FormHelper does exactly what I need: "this_stuff" becomes "This Stuff" for the input's labels.

I guess there's a method for this, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution**
Inflector::humanize($underscored)

```
    Input: apple_pie, some_thing, people_person
    Output: Apple Pie, Some Thing, People Person
```

Comment: [Inflector](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html#Inflector::pluralize) class will do this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Inflector*:

```
static **Inflector::camelize($underscored)**
Input: Apple_pie, some_thing, people_person
Output: ApplePie, SomeThing, PeoplePerson
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html

Comment: Great, thanks. I will use Inflector::humanize($underscored)

        Input: apple_pie, some_thing, people_person
        Output: Apple Pie, Some Thing, People Person